# What is a dtrace error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I'm new to xcode/objc.  When I try to run my app, I get this error:[image]

Any suggestions/help would be great!  I have no idea how this happened.  My best guess is something occurred when I copied some files into different locations, but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, it’s telling you there’s a syntax error in the [DTrace](http://dtrace.org/blogs/about/) file `cpPinJoint.d`. Can you find that file?

Comment: @andrewdotn Yes, I can find it.  There are actually 10 in the project (I'm using Spritebuilder so it is creating all of these for me).  They all look something like this:     ` dependencies: \
  /Users/Lidholt/Projects/SpriteBuilder/SpriteBuilder/libs/cocos2d-iphone/external/Chipmunk/src/cpPinJoint.c \
  external/Chipmunk/include/chipmunk/chipmunk_private.h \ ` But with many more lines, similar to that.

Comment: It seems that Spritebuilder is generating files with a .d extension. That extension normally indicates a DTrace script, but these files are not DTrace scripts. Xcode is treating them as such, which leads to the error. So, either Spritebuilder needs to avoid generating those, avoid adding them to the project(?), or you need to change Xcode's build rules to ignore .d files.

Comment: Or you could stop using cocos2d. :)

Comment: @KenThomases Thanks for the response.  If I were to create a rule to ignore the .d file, would this error still occur when my app goes into review and then possibly get it rejected?

Comment: @matt I know! This is the conclusion I've come to, this is the 100th pain it has caused me.  I just stumbled upon it somehow since I'm starting out.  But I'm 4 months in and built my entire game around it...so..never again!